# How to mute system audio from microphone in Unity?

Tags: unity, audio

How to mute system audio from microphone in Unity?

Or is there some way to have the microphone not capture audio from the game?

Comment: Normally system audio won't be piped through the microphone, but you can enable an OS setting to do that. You may want to check whether your OS is currently configured to route system audio to the microphone channel. You can check the SuperUser or Ask Different StackExchange sites about how to find and change that setting, depending on your OS. See e.g. [Audio output leaking into microphone](https://superuser.com/q/1334718/553271)

Comment: is there a way to do this from the game instead of from OS

Comment: If a game started changing my OS settings I would uninstall it and report it as malware.